# How to concatenate values from relation table in a single query from primary table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have three tables. One is main table with client's data, one is business types list, and third is relation with id's of client with all associated businesses.

Client table, i.e. `Clients`:

```
id | client   | address  | phone   
----------------------------------
1  | John Doe | Address1 | Phone 1
2  | Jane Doe | Address2 | Phone 2
3  | Jack Doe | Address3 | Phone 3
```

Businesses type table, i.e. `Businesses`:

```
id | business
-----------------
1  | Electrician
2  | Plumber
3  | Home remodel
4  | Bathrooms
```

And relation table, saying which client is associated with which business, i.e. `Relations`:

```
c_id | b_id
-----------
1    | 3
1    | 4
2    | 2
2    | 4
3    | 1
3    | 2
3    | 4
```

I need just concatenated business names to be selected in a single row for each client, like this:

Result:

```
id | client   | address  | phone   | business
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | John Doe | Address1 | Phone 1 | Home remodel, Bathrooms
2  | Jane Doe | Address2 | Phone 2 | Plumber, Bathrooms
3  | Jack Doe | Address3 | Phone 3 | Electrician, Plumber, Bathrooms
```

Is that possible with a single query? I have tried a lot of concat and group_concat methods but was unsuccessful. I will really appreciate any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use outer joins, and `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate with a `GROUP BY` clause.

Something like this:

```
SELECT c.id
     , c.client
     , c.address
     , c.phone 
     , GROUP_CONCAT(b.business ORDER BY b.id) AS business 
  FROM `Clients` c
  LEFT
  JOIN `Relations` r
    ON r.c_id = c.id
  LEFT
  JOIN `Businesses` b
    ON b.id = r.b_id
 GROUP
    BY c.id
     , c.client
     , c.address
     , c.phone
```

Comment: Oh yes, I could have grouped by client,address and phone in the inner query as well. Thanks!

Comment: This one is working, but very slowly. Mine client table have >500k rows, and  businesses about 600. Event when I set where clause to limit clients to 4 results, it takes second, second and half... for >100 results it is taking 2 minutes to complete... Something is not optimized, but result is proper, no mistakes.

Comment: Don't know if will happen. I have actually grouped only by id, cause I have lot more columns than in this example, and only id matters in relation and is indexed.

Comment: Ahh.. my bad.. my relation table was improperly indexed... works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
select * from client
inner join
(
select c.id,group_concat(b.business separator ',') as business
from cleints c
inner join relation r
on c.id=r.c_id
inner join business
on r.b_id=b.id
group by c.id) c1
on c.id=c1.id
```

Comment: There is an error in last row... c.id in undefined, it is outside brackets, instead of c.id should be client.id... in any case it is not giving a result, but thanks for try